# HTML5 Call to global function from Worker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have a global function in Utils.js called "sendAndWaitCommand".
When I'm try to call this function form the Worker (name 'uploadToDevice.js'), the Worker crashes.

- Worker Initialization

  ```
  var worker = new Worker('uploadToDevice.js');   
  worker.postMessage(SplitedFile);
  ```
- The Worker (uploadToDevice.js)

  ```
  self.addEventListener('message', function (e)   
  {   
    var SplitedFile = e.data;   
    sendAndWaitCommand(SplitedFile[0].substring(1));//crash here   

  }, false);
  ```
- Utils.js

  ```
   function sendAndWaitCommand(commandToSend)   
   {   
      ...//Some heavy stuff to do.  
   }
  ```

Is there any way to call a global function without the worker will crash?
If not, is there a solution how I can call objects from outside the worker?

Comment: The name of this function is terrifying : `sendAndWaitCommand`. Please, tell us you're not looping until an event arises...

Comment: No, this is embeded Web page, I send command to device (firmware) and I wait for device response

Comment: What do you mean you "wait" ? There's no waiting function in JavaScript.

Comment: It does not matter, it's quite complicated.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript model isn't, naturally, thread based but event based. There's no facility to lock data and ensure their integrity in a multi-thread context.

That's why multi-threading schemes (among them the webworkers) don't allow data sharing (a "global" function is some data and usually points to data through the closure). You **can't** call a "global" function from your webworker. [You communicate with messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

Instead of a global function, you set an event listener :

```
var myWorker = new Worker("my_task.js");
myWorker.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
   // the implementation of your "global function", for example :
   sendAndWaitCommand(oEvent.data.commandToSend);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the code in util.js you would have to import it using the importScripts command:

Example from MDF:

```
importScripts();                        /* imports nothing */
importScripts('foo.js');                /* imports just "foo.js" */
importScripts('foo.js', 'bar.js');      /* imports two scripts */
```

Note that if util.js interacts with the global scope this won't work, since after being imported it will still be in the same scope as your worker. If util.js contains all the code needed to perform the sendAndWaitCommand then that might be a good choice.

If sendAndWaitCommand interacts with your other code, (jquery.ajax, your error handling code, etc.) it would probably be better to setup a message and event system, like so:

```
var worker = new Worker('uploadToDevice.js');
worker.onMessage = function (message) {
    if (// Test here to see if message is result
        message && message[0] == "!")
        myApp.onDone(message.substr(1)) // Removes the ! and calls a function to handel the worker being done
    else // assume the message is a sendAndWaitCommand request
        sendAndWaitCommand(message).then(function (a) {
            worker.postMessage(a); // Send the worker the result
        });  
worker.postMessage(SplitedFile); // Start the worker
```

The second approach will probably involve more refactoring of your code but may be necessary to use workers correctly.